# searching elements of list in file

Tags: python-3.x

The list name is disk and its below:
disks

```
['5000cca025884d5\n', '5000cca025a1ee6\n']
```

The file name is p and its below:

1. c0t5000CCA025884D5Cd0   solaris
         /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca025884d5c

   1. c0t5000CCA025A1EE6Cd0 
        /scsi_vhci/disk@g5000cca025a1ee6c
   2. c3t50060E8007DB981Ad1 
        /pci@400/pci@1/pci@0/pci@8/SUNW,emlxs@0/fp@0,0/ssd@w50060e8007db981a,1
   3. c3t50060E8007DB981Ad2 
        /pci@400/pci@1/pci@0/pci@8/SUNW,emlxs@0/fp@0,0/ssd@w50060e8007db981a,2
   4. c3t50060E8007DB981Ad3 
        /pci@400/pci@1/pci@0/pci@8/SUNW,emlxs@0/fp@0,0/ssd@w50060e8007db981a,3

      10. c3t50060E8007DB981Ad4

i want to search elements of a list in file

Comment: Please help to find the elements of list in a file by using python

Comment: I tried below code but its not working:                                                          for line in q:
  if re.match(disks[0],line):
     print line

Comment: What error are you getting when you try that for loop?

Comment: Thanks  a lot its not giving any output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things to look at here:

I haven't actually used `re.match()` before, but I can see the first issue: Your list of `disks` has a newline character after every entry, so that will mess up matches. Also, `re.match()` only matches from the start of the line. Your lines start with numbers, so you need to search during the line, using `re.search()`. Finally, you should make it case insensitive; one option to d this is to make everything lowercase just as your `disks` list is.

try adapting your loop as so:

```
#.strip() will get rid of new lines and .lower() will make the string lowercase
for line in q:
     if re.search(disks[0].strip(),line.lower()): 
         print line
```

If that doesn't fix it, I would try making it print out `disks[0].strip()` and `line` for every iteration of the loop (not just when it matches the if clause) to make sure it's reading in what you think it is.

Comment: Thank a lot it worked.                                                                                   Please can you give regular expression to search string c0t5000CCA025884D5Cd0

Comment: There are some very good explanations on (this)[http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_reg_expressions.htm] page to help in creating regular expressions in Python, that way you can make your own based off your desires.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me.